# KML to CSV: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following code to convert a KML file into a CSV file, based on what is provided in this link: https://gist.github.com/mciantyre/32ff2c2d5cd9515c1ee7

The code I used is as follows (essentially what is in the link)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def process_coordinate_string(str):
    """
    Take the coordinate string from the KML file, and break it up into [Lat,Lon,Lat,Lon...] for a CSV row
    """
    space_splits = str.split(" ")
    ret = []
    # There was a space in between <coordinates>" "-80.123...... hence the [1:]
    for split in space_splits[1:]:
        comma_split = split.split(',')
        ret.append(comma_split[1])    # lat
        ret.append(comma_split[0])    # lng
    return ret

def open_the_file():
    """
    Open the KML. Read the KML. Open a CSV file. Process a coordinate string to be a CSV row.
    """
    with open('blah.kml', 'r') as f:
        s = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
        with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for coords in s.find_all('coordinates'):
                writer.writerow(process_coordinate_string(coords.string))

open_the_file()
```

However, this throws an error: 
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'. The error is attributed to the second last line (writer.writerow....).

How can this issue be resolved? I am using python 3.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to the byte object before you write, as you have opened the csvfile in the binary mode ie. 'wb'

Use the below line

writer.writerow(process_coordinate_string(coords.string)**.encode('utf-8')**)